# How to run headless VirtualBox in another GUI terminal in Linux?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, terminal, virtual-machine

I want to run Windows and Linux simultaneously through Virtualbox with Linux as a host. Having desktop environment running on GUI terminal (ctrl+alt+f7) I want to run from the first terminal (ctrl+alt+f1):

```
VBoxHeadless --startvm "winXp"
```

I want to have my VirtualBox guest running on another GUI terminal i.e. other than where my desktop environment is on. How can I do that? Right now the command executes but with no "graphical" effect.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure I understand your question, but I think what you want is to start another desktop session. To do that you need to run this in a non-GUI terminal: `startx`.